# Why callback from wcf service is so slow (especially the first time)

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, callback, app-config

I have a service that sends several callbacks per second to connected clients. Why when the service sends a message do the clients get them a few or more seconds later?

Here are the configuration details:

```
        <bindings>
                  <wsDualHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IMyService" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" 
    sendTimeout="00:30:00" useDefaultWebProxy="false" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

                      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                      <security mode="None"/>
                    </binding>
                  </wsDualHttpBinding>
                </bindings>
                <behaviors>
                  <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
                      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
                      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10"
                                maxConcurrentInstances="10"
                                maxConcurrentSessions="5" />
                    </behavior>
                  </serviceBehaviors>
                </behaviors>
```

Comment: There are dozens of reasons. You might want to provide some more details. It could be memory pressure (I've seen this with lots of clients and big messages), CPU pressure, etc. How many clients? How many cores on your server? You might try tweaking your throttling settings.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe could be related to thread creation time.
See here: [WCF service may scale up slowly under load](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538826)

"Depending on the execution time and number of requests received you may notice the WCF execution time increase linearly by approximately 500ms for each request received until the process has created sufficient IOCP threads to service the requests or sustain the incoming load."

A workaround is provided in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same problem, looking at these links to address the issue.

The overview seems that, out-of-the-box, WCF is 'locked down' to prevent DoS vulnerabilities. Essentially, you need to un-throttle the service as described in the links below.

http://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/wcf-improve-performance-with-greater-concurrency/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/11/why-are-wcf-responses-slow-and-setminthreads-does-not-work.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx